# Most efficient way to work with large lists in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I was wondering what is the best way to work with 3 lists of objects in python.

Let’s say I have a list of products - each product is a dict.

Additionally I have 2 more lists one with variants of products  (each variant is a dict) and second list with let’s say retailers (each retailer is a dict).

What I want to do is: I want to map over the product, retailers and variants list and combine them together so in the end I will have list of products and each product will have variants and retailers.

```py
Products = [{"id": 1, 
             "name": "cheese"},…]
   
Variants = [{"product_id": 1, "additional_info":…}, 
            {"product_id": 3, "additional_info":…},
            {"product_id": 1, "additional_info":…},…]

Retailers = [{"product_id": 1, …},…]
```

Let’s say I have 3k of products, 4K of variants and 2k of retailers. I need to map over these lists and assign each retailer and variant to the product.

Comment: Use a real database, or at least a class specialized for dealing with tables. Just because builtin types exist doesn't mean they're always the best choice.

Comment: you might want to look into `pandas`

Comment: Please consider to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve) when you are posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

Using a proper database is probably the right idea if you need to query this data, but combining the three lists into one data structure is relatively simple. The key is to recognize that `Products` should not be a list, but a `dict` whose keys are product IDs.

```
# Assuming the id uniquely identifies a product, rather than
# the id/name pair.
products = {p["id"]: p for p in Products}
```

Then it's a relatively simple O(n) algorithm to update each product in `products` with the variant and retails. (I'm using lists to accumulate variant and retail information when multiple values are associated with a single product.)

```
for v in Variants:
    p_id = v["product_id"]
    info = v["additional_info"]
    products[p_id].setdefault("additional_info", []).append(info)

for r in Retailers:
    p_id = r["product_id"]
    other_data = r["other_stuff"]
    products[p_pid].setdefault("other_stuff", []).append(other_data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'mjust extending @Austin LaShure using pandas's only

## Data

```py
import pandas as pd

products = [{'id':1, 'name':'cheese'}, 
            {'id':2, 'name':'ham'}, 
            {'id':3, 'name':'bread'}]

variants = [
    {'product_id':1, 'additional_info':'has lactose'},
    {'product_id':2, 'additional_info':'not vegan'},
    {'product_id':3, 'additional_info':'has gluten'}
]

retailers = [
    {'product_id':1, 'retailer':'WalMart'},
    {'product_id':2, 'retailer':'Sams'},
    {'product_id':3, 'retailer':'Target'}
    ]
```

## Load data as dataframe

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(products)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(variants)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(retailers)
```

## Merge them

```py
df = pd.merge(
    df1,
    df2,
    left_on=["id"],
    right_on=["product_id"],
    how="outer")

df = pd.merge(
    df,
    df3,
    left_on=["id"],
    right_on=["product_id"],
    how="outer")
print(df)
```

```sh
   id    name  product_id_x additional_info  product_id_y retailer
0   1  cheese             1     has lactose             1  WalMart
1   2     ham             2       not vegan             2     Sams
2   3   bread             3      has gluten             3   Target
```

Here I'm taking the most general case using `outer` join if you want an `inner` you can specify it and eventually drop the `product_id` after each merge.

Answer (score -1):

I am still pretty new with pandas, but big lists and dicts are much easier to manipulate with pandas.

this code:

```
import pandas as pd

products = [{'id':1, 'name':'cheese'}, {'id':2, 'name':'ham'}, {'id':3, 'name':'bread'}]

variants = [
    {'product_id':1, 'additional_info':'has lactose'},
    {'product_id':2, 'additional_info':'not vegan'},
    {'product_id':3, 'additional_info':'has gluten'}
]

retailers = [
    {'product_id':1, 'retailer':'WalMart'},
    {'product_id':2, 'retailer':'Sams'},
    {'product_id':3, 'retailer':'Target'}
    ]


list_of_data = []
for p in products:
    id = p['id']
    name = p['name']
    for i in retailers:
        if i['product_id'] == id:
            seller = i['retailer']
    for j in variants:
        if j['product_id'] == id:
            additional_info = j['additional_info']

    data = pd.Series(data=[id, name, seller, additional_info],
    index=['product_id', 'name', 'retailer', 'additonal info'])
    list_of_data.append(data)

frame = pd.DataFrame(list_of_data)
```

takes the data you have in your current code and put it into a dataframe. The dataframe object has a lot of useful properties and functions.  If you aren't going to use a database, [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of lists of dictionaries, try to use dictionaries that have unique keys.  Once you have that, updating one of the dictionaries with the others can be done with the `.update()` method.

```
products = [{"id": 1, "name": "cheese"}, {"id": 2, "name": "milk"}]
variants = [
    {"product_id": 1, "additional_info": "blah blah blah"},
    {"product_id": 3, "additional_info": "blah"},
    {"product_id": 1, "additionalinfo": "blorgh"},
]
retailers = [
    {"product_id": 1, "retail_name": "name:"},
    {"product_id": 2, "retail_name": "name2"},
]

product_dict = {
    product["id"]: {k: v for k, v in product.items() if k != "id"}
    for product in products
}
variant_dict = {
    variant["product_id"]: {k: v for k, v in variant.items() if k != "product_id"}
    for variant in variants
}
retailer_dict = {
    retailer["product_id"]: {k: v for k, v in retailer.items() if k != "product_id"}
    for retailer in retailers
}

for product_id, product in product_dict.items():
    product.update(variant_dict.get(product_id, {}))
    product.update(retailer_dict.get(product_id, {}))

print(product_dict)

# Prints
# {1: {'additionalinfo': 'blorgh', 'name': 'cheese', 'retail_name': 'name:'},
#  2: {'name': 'milk', 'retail_name': 'name2'}}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use a relational database, the MongoDB would be your best bet.

Python has PyMongo :

- https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

[snapshot of MongoDB database & collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RsCf.png)
[enter image description here]

The above image represents a MongoDB database : python_inventory_dict
with collections ("tables") as per requirements

Combining collections:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.